# Require that generic type overload operators and result of operation also overload operators

Tags: generics, types, rust

I am trying to implement a kind of `HashSet` that can store which hashes have been encountered (without associating a value).

I'm having trouble with this:

- I want the structure to be generic over types that implement `Div`, `Rem` and `Eq` (int-like).
- For it to work, I need the output of `Div` and `Rem` to also implement `Div`, `Rem` and `Eq` (I think). I'm willing to disqualify types that don't meet this criteria.
- The types also need to interact with an integer constant that I can't get to be of a dynamic type.

I've tried to reduce it to a minimal example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a5b8f0e8cefe1723c75174a92582bfc4&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
use std::ops::{ Rem, Div };

const X: i32 = 16;

pub trait Int: Rem + Div + Eq + Sized {}

impl Int for i32 {}
impl Int for usize {}
// also other int types

pub fn stuff<T: Int>(arg: T) -> T {
    (arg / X) % X
}
```

(I also have a more elaborate [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9cc2440ae44e142f6ccde4c35d21c992&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) to show what I tried).

But while I understand the errors I get, I don't know how to resolve them:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> main.rs:13:12
   |
13 |     (arg / BINS) % BINS
   |            ^^^^ expected type parameter, found i32
   |
   = note: expected type `T`
              found type `i32`

error[E0369]: binary operation `%` cannot be applied to type `<T as std::ops::Div>::Output`
  --> main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     (arg / BINS) % BINS
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Rem` might be missing for `<T as std::ops::Div>::Output`
```

Nightly features are fine.

Comment: Applying the duplicate to your case: `fn stuff<T>(arg: T) -> T
where
    T: Div<i32>,
    T::Output: Rem<i32, Output = T>,`